# Why cannot increase ylim in basic bar plot?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a bar plot for qualitative variables. In the following situation:

```
library(ISLR)
df <- College
barplot(table(df$Private))
```

Why does the count for "yes" fo past the limit of the Y-axis?

```
library(ISLR)
df <- College
barplot(table(df$Private), ylim=700)
```

To correct this, why do I get an error for when I try to increase the limit of the y-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a *range* from ... to ... . The correct input is:

```
ylim = c(0, 700)
```

Feel free to take whatever else instead of `0`.